# Is there a law stating why a quark never decays weakly into a quark of the same weak-isospin ($T_3$)?

Tags: standard-model, quarks, weak-interaction, electroweak, isospin-symmetry

So I read multiple articles on weak isospin and [one of them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_isospin) stated that

> "a quark never decays weakly into a quark of the same $T_3$".

If this is true, can someone please explain what law states this?

Answer (score 6):

The law is called:

> "***There are no flavor-changing neutral currents***",

given the association of $T_3$ with electric charge—the hyper charge remaining invariant, naturally.

At tree level, it is ***absolute***, given the celebrated flavor-diagonal couplings of the *Z* boson.

But at one loop, it is violated by a [very-very small amount, suppressed by the GIM mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavor-changing_neutral_current).
Still, the rare decay [$B^0_s\to \phi \phi$](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ex/0502044) has been observed, amounting to $b\to ss\bar s$, dominated by [penguin loop diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penguin_diagram).

[image]

(For  leptons, this mechanism, is also the reason for the fantastically small rate anticipated for $\mu \to e \gamma$, a cleaner, non-hadronic mode of the essentially same phenomenon.)

Answer (score 0):

The term in the standard model lagrangian which couples quarks of different flavors looks like
$$(\overline{u}_L,\overline{c}_L,\overline{t}_L)\gamma^\mu V_{CKM} \begin{pmatrix}d_L\\s_L\\b_L\end{pmatrix}W_\mu^- + \text{h.c}$$

where the row and columns are in flavor space. The up type quarks have $T_3=1/2$ and the down type quarks $T_3=-1/2$.
As you can see there are no couplings amongst the up or down type quarks with themselves.